# Postgresql: Combining similarity with tsvector

Tags: postgresql

I got a database table containing more than 50 million records
which i need to full text search as fast as possible.

On a smaller table i just had a index on the text column and i use the similarity function to get similar results. I was also able to sort by the result of similarity().

Now, after my table is a lot bigger, i switched to tsvector. I created a column for the tsvector result and a trigger which updates the column before insert or update. After that i can search ultra fast (<100ms).

The problem is that i would like to use a combination of both tsvector and similarity.

### Example

My table contains the following data.

```
| MyColumn |
------------
| Apple    |
| Orange   |
| ...      |
```

But if i search for "App" i don't get "Apple" back.

Any ideas on how to get a fast "like/similar" search with a "score/similarity" score ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES

> Also, * can be attached to a lexeme to specify prefix matching:

smth like that?.:

```
postgres=# with c(v) as (values('Apple'),('App'),('application'),('apricote'))
select v,to_tsvector(v),to_tsvector(v) @@ to_tsquery('app:*') from c;
      v      | to_tsvector | ?column?
-------------+-------------+----------
 Apple       | 'appl':1    | t
 App         | 'app':1     | t
 application | 'applic':1  | t
 apricote    | 'apricot':1 | f
(4 rows)

postgres=# with c(v) as (values('Apple'),('App'),('application'),('apricote'))
select v,to_tsvector(v),to_tsvector(v) @@ to_tsquery('ap:*') from c;
      v      | to_tsvector | ?column?
-------------+-------------+----------
 Apple       | 'appl':1    | t
 App         | 'app':1     | t
 application | 'applic':1  | t
 apricote    | 'apricot':1 | t
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers @dknaack 's question. Prefix helps it in the right direction, but misspellings are taken into account with `similarity`. He's looking for a combination of the two methods, not just a solution to his single example.